# SQL: Remove spaces in all tables

Tags: mysql, loops, spaces

I want to remove all spaces in front and after the entries in all my columns in all my tables. For one column I use `UPDATE table_name SET column_name= LTRIM(RTRIM(column_name))` which works well. However, I would have to copy and paste all the names in order to do this for all columns and tables.

Is there a simpler way, e.g. by looping trough somehow? A loop for one table would be very useful already!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic query wich will loop against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table and construct your final string wich will updates all the columns.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```

will gives you the name of all columns. Then you can filter on column type or whatever you want.